# Telethon send image with spoiler

Tags: python, telethon

How can I send image with spoiler in telethon?
I use **telethon-1.27.0**.

This is the code I'm using:
`client.send_message(user, file="/something.png")`

I tried to use `has_spoiler=True` but got an error message

> send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'has_spoiler' or 'spoiler' and etc.

> in sendmessage i found that parameter - Message sent. Return Value Message(id=123, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=123), date=datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 5, 23, 11, 49, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='123', out=True, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False, pinned=False, noforwards=False, from_id=None, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to=None, media=MessageMediaPhoto(**spoiler=False**, photo=Photo(id=5982148115249082446

Comment: What's the problem with that code?

Comment: with spoiler, new flag in telegram - has_spoiler = True

Comment: The problem is that you didn't use `has_spoiler=True`? So why don't you use it?

Comment: sorry, but i am really cant understand it, when i try: 
send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'has_spoiler'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Telethon v1.27 or greater, and then manually construct the correct media (in this case, [`InputMediaUploadedPhoto`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/input_media_uploaded_photo.html)):

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, types

...

file = ...  # path to your file 'photo.png' or file object

uploaded = await client.upload_file(file)
await client.send_file(chat, types.InputMediaUploadedPhoto(
    uploaded,
    spoiler=True,
))
```

Comment: yes its work fine, thanks alot! on image well done.
its realy did with 1 message - image (spoiler) + text?

client.send_message - Exception while sending the message - send_message() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given


now its work with 2 message (file + message)
        uploaded = 'img.png'
        image = await client.send_file(user, types.InputMediaUploadedPhoto(uploaded, spoiler=True))
        text = await client.send_message(user, "text", parse_mode="html")

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains how to send spoilers.

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/examples/working-with-messages.html#sending-spoilers-hidden-text

> The current markdown and HTML parsers do not offer a way to send spoilers yet. You need to use MessageEntitySpoiler so that parts of the message text are shown under a spoiler.
>
> The simplest way to do this is to modify the builtin parsers to support sending these new message entities with the features they already provide.

The cited
[recipe](https://web.archive.org/web/20230205224058/https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Sending-spoilers-and-custom-emoji)
shows how to define parse / unparse methods in `class CustomMarkdown`.
When it sees `[hidden text](spoiler)` and finds a literal
match on "spoiler" it edits in a `MessageEntitySpoiler`
object that will produce the desired effect.

Comment: yes, i found it too. but this is for text example only, not for files.
but i try. thanks